# where to find google analytics dimensions values

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to implement my own google analytics reporting UI where users pick metrics and dimensions and then pick the filters according to what the user have already chosen and my question is there any way to get all the dimensions values? for example the dimension "country" can take the value of all the countries(USA,Fance,etc...). I've did some research on google but found nothing. any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like Analytics Edge extension for Excel to do exactly what you're trying to do.

If that doesn't completely solve what you're doing, the extension does pull all the pullable fields from GA. It also gives you an insight into what kind of request it sends to G to pull the data. Very useful for debugging, but also for learning the reporting API.

Alternatively, there's documentation on the API here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4

Make sure you know whether you're using GA4 or GA UA. They have different APIs.